# Правильно ли написано предложение? Есть ли ошибки?

Tags: грамотная-речь, орфография

Не ожидал увидеть от тебя комментарий на странице

Answer (score 1):

Я тут не уверен, может, кто-то что-то ещё скажет, но на мой взгляд, «от тебя» находится не в правильном месте.

«Увидеть» тут переходный глагол, он требует дополнения без предлога: *«увидеть тебя»*, *«увидеть комментарий»*.

*«…увидеть от тебя комментарий…»* — звучит не очень.

Думаю лучше: *«Не ожидал **увидеть комментарий от тебя** на странице».*

А ещё лучше, без лишних предлогов: *«Не ожидал **увидеть твой комментарий** на странице».*

Comment: Это разговорный стиль. Вполне возможен такой синтаксис.